# Tools available to analyze and benchmark the battery usage of android application

Tags: android, performance, performance-testing, battery

I want to accurately estimate the power usage of my android application. ie, analyze the power usage through the Network usage, GPS usage etc.

I found that [Battery Historian](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/battery-historian.html) as a solution. But it does not provide the real time analysis.

Is there any other tool that analyzes the battery usage of android applications?

How can I benchmark the battery usage of my application?

Comment: Maybe this will help you ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47303330/5130239

Comment: Thanks Dus. It is like  Battery Historian and not provide real time statistics and not able to create a benchmark measurements based on its output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article that can help you out.

https://testlio.com/blog/the-secret-art-of-battery-testing-on-android/

Actually for testing out battery you have to keep in mind lots of parameter like what services your app is using , how much cpu and for how long your app uses, combining all these can help you reduce the battery consumption of your app.

Answer (score 1):

> But it does not provide the real time analysis.

For real-time analysis, an built Android Monitor already exists which is a profiling tool and gives you accurate real-time battery drain usage.

From Android 3.0, there is a new profiler tool which you can check out.
[Android Profiler in Android Studio 3.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/android-profiler.html)  .

> How can I benchmark the battery usage of my application?

Also, I would recommend you to read other great answers on the SO community. : [Testing Battery Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566910/testing-battery-usage)